# Does ActiveRecord save a belongs_to association when saving main object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

If I have two models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

If I do:

```
post = Post.new
user = User.new
post.user = user
post.save
```

Does the user get saved as well and the primary key properly assigned in `post`'s `user_id` field?

Answer (score 21):

ActiveRecord `belongs_to` associations have the ability to be autosaved along with the parent model, but the functionality is off by default. To enable it:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :autosave => true
end
```

Comment: Weird. I turned that flag on, and doing the same as above still gives me `> post.errors #=> #<OrderedHash {:user_id=>["can't be blank"]}>` and `user.new_record? #=> true`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually the functionality is **on** by default. You must set it to false in order to turn it off, otherwise all associations will be saved automatically.

Comment: @OdeeOdum: That's not true, I had a problem like this and setting autosave: true in rails 3 fixed the issue.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL, Actually it is the default behavior. According to the ActiveRecord::AutosaveAssocation documentation    
    When the :autosave option is not present new associations are saved.

Comment: Mhhh, I need to check, because I tried without it and it wasn't working. When I added the autosave option it started working fine, and I didn't change anything else meanwhile.

Comment: From the ActiveRecord docs: `Note that autosave: false is not same as not declaring :autosave. When the :autosave option is not present then new association records are saved but the updated association records are not saved.`

Answer (score 8):

I believe you want:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts, :autosave => true
end
```

In other words, when saving a User record, seek out all records on the other side of the 'posts' association and save them.

Answer (score 3):

The [belongs_to API documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) says (Rails 4.2.1):

> `:autosave`
>
> If true, always save the associated object or destroy it if marked for destruction, when saving the parent object.
>
> If false, never save or destroy the associated object.
>
> By default, only save the associated
>   object if it’s a new record.
>
> Note that accepts_nested_attributes_for sets :autosave to true.

In your case user is new record so it will be auto saved.

The last sentence about `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is also missed by many.