# Is there any before_update hook for an activerecord object if the object in the child relation is saved and touch is set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team, touch: true
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  before_save :update_popularity
  before_update :update_popularity

  def popularity
    #secret algorythm
  end

private
  def update_popularity
    # This is not called
  end
end


User.first.name = 'John'
```

When I save a user I would like to update the team popularity as well. However the before_filter doesn't seem to be invoked?

Is there any proper way for doing this?

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231415/does-activerecord-save-a-belongs-to-association-when-saving-main-object

Comment: I tried the callback is still not called.

Comment: What about calling the models before_save or after_save callback, find the associated team within the method and call its update_popularity?

Comment: @shadowhorst That is what I tried to avoid... To manually call that method from the child...

Comment: I've never seen before_filter used in a model before:  usually it's for controllers, and in the model you have before_save, before_create etc.  Is this a new addition to rails?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Sorry... I misspelled the hooks... The are corrected now.

Comment: Finnally I put an after_save in the child model and called the hook in the parrent manually from the childs after_save hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `before_update :update_popularity`

Update:

After reviewing the API doc of `touch` method [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch), they say:

> Please note that no validation is performed and only the `after_touch` callback is
>   executed.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled my before filters... It tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer. you have to use `after_touch` callback.